# herokuの本番環境ではjqueryのdatepickerのカレンダーが表示されない。

Tags: jquery, heroku

初心者です。

ご質問させて頂きます。

ローカル環境ではjqueryによるカレンダーが正常に表示されるのですが、herokuにpushした後、本番環境ではjqueryによるカレンダーが表示されません。どこに間違いがあるのでしょうか教えて頂けると幸いです。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<!-- jqueryの埋め込み -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-ja.min.js"></script>

<!-- jquery UI で　startを　ui-lightness等にかえることによりカレンダーのcssを変更可能 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" >

<!-- 地図の大きさ指定 -->
<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'>
  <div id="custom_style" style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap
({ 
  provider:
   { zoom:      15,
      center:    new google.maps.LatLng(34.839449, 134.6939047),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles:    mapStyle}, 

      internal: {id: 'custom_style'}},

       function(){
        //マーカーを追加していく
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%== @ash.to_json %>);
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%== @hash.to_json %>);

  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.getMap().setZoom(yourValue);
});
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <!-- 地図の右上にタイトル表示 -->
    <div id="custom_style" style="z-index:0; position:absolute;"></div>
    <img src="/assets/icon.png"
       style="z-index:1;position:absolute;left:90px;top:10px;" />

<!-- カレンダーの表示　-->
<div id ="calendar">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
</script>
<!-- hiddenをtextにかえると日付のテキストボックスが出てくる -->
 <input type="hidden" id="datepicker" >

  <script >
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "showOn", 'button');
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "buttonImageOnly", true);
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "buttonImage", '/assets/icon_calendar.png');

  });

  <!-- 日付の取得 -->
  $("#calender").datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
var date1 = dateText; // 08/13/2014の形
var date2 = $(this).datepicker( 'getDate' ); //　Wed Aug 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0900　の形
alert(date1);
}
});

  <!-- 日付選択時のアクション -->
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
    alert(dateText);
  }
});
</script>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: これは素の HTML では無く、何かのテンプレートか何かですよね。これが HTML に展開される時、ローカルと結果が変るのだと思います。最終結果の HTML を確認してみて下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

直接の回答ではないのですが、
ローカルでは開けるものがサーバーだと開けない、ということは外部参照するつもりのJavaScriptが読めていないのが原因ではないでしょうか？

この手の調査時は、ブラウザのデバッグツール（IEならF12押下、Chromeでも同様）を使ってエラー情報を見るのが特定への近道だと思います。